# Expand list when mouse click on list

Tags: html, css

I have created drop down menu using list item. The list is expanding when the mouse hover, but I need do when the mouse click on list the list should expand.

CSS:

```css
.top-level 
{
 background:#999;
 width:100%;
 line-height: 25px;
}
.top-level li 
{
 border-bottom: #fff solid;
 border-top: #fff solid;
 border-width: 1px;       
}
.top-level li:hover 
{
 background: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.top-level li:hover >ul
{
 background: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 display :inline ;
}
.second-level
{            
 background:#999;
 width:100%;
 line-height: 25px;      
 list-style: none; 
 display: none; 
}
.second-level > li
{    
 display: inline-block;        
 border-bottom: #fff solid;
 border-top: #fff solid;
 border-width: 1px; 
 background:#999;       
}
.second-level > li:hover 
{ 
 background: #fff; 
 text-decoration: none;
}
.second-level li:hover >ul
{
 background: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 display :inline ;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="top-  
level">                                                                
  <li> <span>Test - A</span>
    <ul  class="second-level">
      <li> <span>Test - A1</span></li>
      <li> <span>Test - A2</span>
        <ul  class="second-level">
          <li> <span>Test - A21</span></li>
          <li> <span>Test - A21</span></li>
          <li> <span>Test - A21</span></li>
          <li> <span>Test - A21</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <span>Test - A3</span></li>
      <li> <span>Test - A4</span></li>
      <li> <span>Test - A5</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span>Test - B</span></li>
  <li> <span>Test - C</span></li>
  <li> <span>Test - D</span></li>
</ul>
```

Above is my test coding for CSS and HTML. Please look at this code and give me the solution for mouse click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and apply a click event to the top-level `li`.
Something like:

```
$('.top-level').on ('click', function (){
 $('.top-level > li').css ('display', 'block');
});
```

I am not entirely sure of what your HTML looks like, but this is the general idea.
You will also need to come up with a function to close the menu.
There are plenty of resources on the internet for examples and tutorials on writing jQuery.